# How do extract text in complete sentences/paragraphs with Python?

Tags: python

I am currently trying to convert a PDF into text for the purposes of ML, but whenever I do so, it returns the text in broken lines, which is making the text less readable.

Here is what I am currently doing to convert the text:

```
import fitz, spacy

with fitz.open("asset/example2.pdf") as doc:
    text_ = ""
    for page in doc:
        text_ += page.getText()
```

and here are the results:

```
Animals - Animals have
always been near my
heart and it has led me to
involve myself in animal
rights events and
protests. It still stays as
a dream of mine to go
volunteer at an animal
sanctuary one day.
Food Travel - Through a
diet change, I have
found my love for food
and exploring different
food cultures across the
world. I feel confident
saying that I could write
an extensive
encyclopaedia for great
vegan restaurants.
```

what would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: We can't really help you if we don't know what the text is supposed to look like. It would help if you could attach a screenshot or an excerpt from the text.

Comment: `text_ += page.getText().rstrip() + " "`  so you will change the newlines with spaces.  You can put this in a conditional that only does the change if the line doesn't end with '.'

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what result you are looking for but you if you would like all the text to be on one line you can use `text.replace('\n', '')`. If you want. You may also find `text.split(separator)` and `separator.join(list)` useful for formating your string, for example:

```
string = 'This is my \nfirst sentance. This \nsecond sentance\n.'
print(string)
string = string.replace('\n', '')
sentanceList = string.split('.')
string = '.\n'.join(sentanceList)
print(string)
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Apologies I should've mentioned, this will be formatting resume's which can sometimes be random, but i just wanted the text to be extract as it was written on the pdf, sometimes full stops arent used. I wasnt sure if I was extracting it wrong

Comment: I still don't understand what the desired output is, you have stated that you want it to be extracted as it is in the pdf, but I can't see the pdf, what is the output you want?

Comment: just complete sentence, when I extract text from the PDF, it just has broken sentences on new lines instead of having complete text.

Comment: so does `text.replace('\n', ''` fix that?

Comment: I ended up using NLTK to try and make grammatical sense of a sentence and basically reformat the text, thank you though